# Magento 2 - Add a template block in a CMS page via layout update

Tags: magento2, cms-pages

I'm trying to include a new template block in a CMS page in the admin via layout updates. 
Here is the xml:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="homepage.carousel" template="homepage/carousel.phtml" before="-" />
```

The carousel template has been added in [theme-folder]/Magento_Theme/templates/homepage/carousel.phtml. Then I run:

1. `bin/magento cache:flush`
2. `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

No luck, so then I moved the template to [theme-folder]/Magento_Cms/templates/homepage/carousel.phtml. I re-run the above commands but still no luck. Then I changed the CMS page "New Theme" and set it to my custom theme and re-run the above commands and still no luck.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The error was that I forgot to wrap the XML inside a <referenceContainer name="content">. So the fix to this issue is to add the xml update inside <referenceContainer name="content"></referenceContainer>

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer to your own question, and accept it. This helps others who are having the same issue.

Comment: In `template="homepage/carousel.phtml"` can try with `template="Magento_Theme::homepage/carousel.phtml"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I forgot to wrap the XML inside a `<referenceContainer name="content">`. So the XML should look like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="homepage.carousel" template="Magento_Theme::homepage/carousel.phtml" before="-" />
</referenceContainer>
```

And the other thing is that you should add the magento module inside the template src E.g:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="homepage.carousel" template="Magento_Theme::homepage/carousel.phtml" before="-" />
```

Kudos for this last part to [Ankit Shah](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/42297/ankit-shah)